# Iterating over objects returned by Linqdatasource

Tags: c#, casting, iteration, linqdatasource

I have a GridView, with filtering and pagination (10 at a time), bound to a Linqdatasource.  All this works.

But how can I get the Ids of all the data retrieved in the LinqDataSource after it has finished retrieval of all rows?

I have this method, and e.Result is an object data type containing List for this grid

```
protected void LinqDataSource_Selected(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)  // event fires after data retrieval complete.
{
    List<int> ids = new List<int>();
    if (e.TotalRowCount > 0)
    {
        for (int idx = 0; idx < e.TotalRowCount; idx++)
        {
            Foo foo = (Foo)(e.Result[idx]);  // error cannot apply indexing to expression of type object
            ids.Add(foo.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

My error is iterating over an object, how can this be done?

Comment: what kind of list does e.Result contain? if e.Result is an object, you have to cast it to the appropiate type of the list in order to apply indexing

Comment: and also, you are missing a parenthesis: Foo foo = (Foo)(e.Result[idx]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do:

```
protected void LinqDataSource_Selected(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)  // event fires after data retrieval complete.
{
    List<int> ids = new List<int>();
    if (e.TotalRowCount > 0)
    {
        List<Foo> fooList = ((IEnumerable)e.Result).ToList();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < fooList.Count; idx++)
        {
            Foo foo = fooList[idx];
            ids.Add(foo.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
protected void LinqDataSource_Selected(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)  // event fires after data retrieval complete.
{
    List<int> ids = new List<int>();
    if (e.TotalRowCount > 0)
    {
        foreach(Foo foo in (IEnumerable)e.Result)
        {
            ids.Add(foo.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

If your Selected is a result of a filtered view, e.Result will be an IEnumerable of anonymous type, so getting the information will most likely require using an IQueryable and a viewmodel object.

Answer (score 1):

`e.Result` is an `object`, so you need to cast it to a List type to be able to apply indexing:

```
Foo foo = ((List<Foo>)(e.Result))[idx];
```

Comment: e.Result might be an Enumerable, so it's safer to use .ToList() to ensure you can actually get a List out.